# ffmpeg extract frame and get timestamp based on creation time for each extracted frame in exif or txt

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, frame, exif, extract

I try to extract frames from a underwater survey video using ffmpeg. the extracted frames should be merged with a gps position based on a timestamp later in the process. the code i use to extract the frames is:

`ffmpeg -i GOPR0173.MP4 -qscale:v 2 -r 1 frames/%4d.jpg`.

I need a solution to get the real timestamp of the frame based on the survey datetime, so that the timestamp of the frame equals the real time when the video was created. Ideally the timestamp is saved in the images exif or if this is not possible in a seperate textfile and the timestamp is used as name of the files like 2020_01_01_HH_MM_SS.jpg.

My idea is to use the creation_time of the video add the timestamp of the frame to this and store the result in the exif of the extracted frame or if this is not possible in a txt file.

Im new to ffmpeg and really lost and would appreciate any help to solve this task!
If anyone could provide me the necessary code, that would be awesome!

```
C:\Unterwasserfotos>ffmpeg -i GOPR0173.MP4 -vstats -qscale:v 2 -r 0.1 frames/%4d.jpg
ffmpeg version git-2020-01-21-fc6fde2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls
 --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enabl
e-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-
libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwol
ame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enab
le-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable
-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable
-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enabl
e-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 66.100 / 58. 66.100
  libavformat    58. 35.104 / 58. 35.104
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 71.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GOPR0173.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-01-21T12:33:10.000000Z
    firmware        : HD4.02.05.00.00
  Duration: 00:02:21.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30152 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR
 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30000 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-21T12:33:10.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AVC
      encoder         : GoPro AVC encoder
      timecode        : 12:33:11:16
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (defa
ult)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-21T12:33:10.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AAC
      timecode        : 12:33:11:16
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-21T12:33:10.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 12:33:11:16
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-21T12:33:10.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro SOS
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'frames/%4d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    firmware        : HD4.02.05.00.00
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.104
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s,
 0.10 fps, 0.10 tbn, 0.10 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-21T12:33:10.000000Z
      handler_name    :         GoPro AVC
      timecode        : 12:33:11:16
      encoder         : Lavc58.66.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   16 fps=0.3 q=2.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:02:40.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=7076 speed=3.26x
video:1938kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for my task. The core component is a nice batch-script (see below) i found and adopted to my needs.

1. Place the programs *exiftool*, *ffmpeg*, *Namexif*, *GeoSetter*, the batch-script and the videofile in one folder.
2. Read the timestamp from the gopro videofile with *Mediainfo*.
3. Insert video-filename and timestamp in the batch-script (line 34 and 63)
4. Run batch-script to extract a frame each second (Timestamp placed in exif)
5. Use *GeoSetter* to merge the frames with a *.gpx*-file (Coordinates placed in exif)
6. Use *Namexif* to replace the filenames of the frames with date and time based on their exif

Batch-script:

```
@echo off
rem Ksheesh Geotag Video Frames 0.0.1
rem 
rem Extract frames from video every X seconds and geotag them using GPS data file.
rem Requires exiftool and ffmpeg.

rem Copyright (c) 2017 krzysiu.net
rem 
rem Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
rem of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
rem in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
rem to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
rem copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
rem furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
rem 
rem The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
rem copies or substantial portions of the Software.
rem 
rem THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
rem IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
rem FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
rem AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
rem LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
rem OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
rem SOFTWARE.

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Config starts here. Remember:
rem * Paths and names: don't use quotes, even if it has spaces in the string. 
rem * Binaries: if they are in shared path, you may set just the binary name, 
rem             i.e. "ffmpeg" (without quotes) for ffmpegBin variable.

rem Input video file
set videoFile=GOPR0173.MP4

rem Prefix which will be added to image file names
set framePrefix=frame_

rem Output directory for frame images (must exist; without trailing slash)
set outputDirectory=%cd%

rem Path to ffmpeg binary.
set ffmpegBin=ffmpeg.exe

rem Path to exiftool binary.
set exiftoolBin=exiftool.exe

rem Padding digit count (1-9) in frame file names (i.e. 3 will make 001.jpg and 2 will make 01.jpg)
set paddingDigits=4

rem Get frame every X seconds.
set getFrameEvery=1

rem Date and time of the start of the video. You may use:
rem * DateTimeOriginal - if the file has DateTimeOriginal tag
rem * FileCreateDate - set timestamp to file creation date
rem * FileModifyDate - set timestamp to file modify date
rem * 0 - own timestamp (see videoTimestamp variable)
set dateSource=0

rem If dateSource is set to 0, set here date and time of the start of the video.
rem The format is yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss
set videoTimestamp=2020:01:21 13:28:33

rem The source of GPS data, i.e. GPX or other supported file. Wildcards are also
rem possible, e.g. gpsDataFile=c:\gps_data\*.gpx
set gpsDataFile=2020-01-21_gps.gpx
rem Config ends here.

set exifDateParam=-tagsFromFile "%videoFile%" "-datetimeoriginal<%dateSource%"
if %dateSource% equ 0 set exifDateParam="-datetimeoriginal=%videoTimestamp%Z"

if not exist "%outputDirectory%" (
set errMsg=Can't access output directory ^(%outputDirectory%^)
goto error
)

if not exist "%videoFile%" (
set errMsg=Can't access video file ^(%videoFile%^)
goto error
)
pushd %outputDirectory%

echo Extracting frames...
%ffmpegBin% -loglevel error -hide_banner -stats -i "%videoFile%" -qscale:v 2 -vf fps=fps=1/%getFrameEvery%:start_time=0:round=zero %framePrefix%%%0%paddingDigits%d.jpg
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
set errMsg=ffmpeg returned error
goto error
)
echo Done!
echo.

echo Setting base timestamp to files.
set fileNumber=0
%exiftoolBin% %exifDateParam% -overwrite_original -globaltimeshift "+0:0:0 0:0:!timeShift!" "%framePrefix%*.jpg"
echo Done!
echo.

echo Setting timestamp offsets.
for %%f in ("%framePrefix%*.jpg") do (
set /a "timeShift=!fileNumber!*%getFrameEvery%"
if !fileNumber! neq 0 %exiftoolBin% -P -m -overwrite_original "-datetimeoriginal+=0:0:0 0:0:!timeShift!" "%%~nxf"
set /a "fileNumber=!fileNumber!+1"
)
echo Done!
echo.
goto theend

:error
echo %errMsg%. Exitting.

:theend
pause
popd
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I also modified the above code.  It now accepts command line parameters which allow for automated processing of multiple mp4 files through the use of spreadsheet to piece together command lines.

MODIFIED FOR UNCOMPRESSED TIFF(large files)

SYNTAX:
`batchfilename.bat path(with terminating backslash) filename(without extension, currently assumed to be MP4) number_of_seconds_between_frames(numeric) date(xxxx:xx:xx year:month:day) time(xx:xx:xx.x)`

```
xxxx.bat code:
    @echo off
    rem Ksheesh Geotag Video Frames 0.0.1  
    rem MODIFIED FOR UNCOMPRESSED TIFF USING COMMAND LINE PARAMETERS
    rem SYNTAX: batchfilename.bat path(with terminating backslash) filename(without extension, currently
    rem assummed to be MP4) number_of_seconds_between_frames(numeric) date(xxxx:xx:xx year:month
    rem :day) time(xx:xx:xx.x)
    rem 
    rem Extract frames from video every X seconds and geotag them using GPS data file.
    rem Requires exiftool and ffmpeg.
    
    rem Copyright (c) 2017 krzysiu.net
    rem 
    rem Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    rem of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    rem in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    rem to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    rem copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    rem furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
    rem 
    rem The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
    rem copies or substantial portions of the Software.
    rem 
    rem THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    rem IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    rem FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    rem AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    rem LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    rem OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
    rem SOFTWARE.
    
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem Config starts here. Remember:
    rem * Paths and names: don't use quotes, even if it has spaces in the string. 
    rem * Binaries: if they are in shared path, you may set just the binary name, 
    rem             i.e. "ffmpeg" (without quotes) for ffmpegBin variable.
    
    rem Input video file
    set videoFile=%1%2.mp4
    rem Prefix which will be added to image file names
    set framePrefix=%2GEO_
    echo %framePrefix%
    rem Output directory for frame images (must exist; without trailing slash)
    set outputDirectory=%1GPStiff
    md "%outputDirectory%"
    
    rem Path to ffmpeg binary.
    set ffmpegBin=q:\drone\djimp3tiff\ffmpeg.exe
    
    rem Path to exiftool binary.
    set exiftoolBin=q:\drone\djimp3tiff\exiftool.exe
    
    rem Padding digit count (1-9) in frame file names (i.e. 3 will make 001.jpg and 2 will make 01.jpg)
    set paddingDigits=4
    
    rem Get frame every X seconds.
    set getFrameEvery=%3
    
    rem Date and time of the start of the video. You may use:
    rem * DateTimeOriginal - if the file has DateTimeOriginal tag
    rem * FileCreateDate - set timestamp to file creation date
    rem * FileModifyDate - set timestamp to file modify date
    rem * 0 - own timestamp (see videoTimestamp variable)
    set dateSource=0
    
    rem If dateSource is set to 0, set here date and time of the start of the video.
    rem The format is yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss
    rem set videoTimestamp=2021:10:21 20:30:26.7
    set videoTimestamp=%4 %5
    
    rem The source of GPS data, i.e. GPX or other supported file. Wildcards are also
    rem possible, e.g. gpsDataFile=c:\gps_data\*.gpx
    set gpsDataFile=%1%2.gpx
    rem Config ends here.
    
    set exifDateParam=-tagsFromFile "%videoFile%" "-datetimeoriginal<%dateSource%"
    if %dateSource% equ 0 set exifDateParam="-datetimeoriginal=%videoTimestamp%Z"
    
    
    if not exist "%outputDirectory%" (
    set errMsg=Can't access output directory ^(%outputDirectory%^)
    goto error
    )
    
    if not exist "%videoFile%" (
    set errMsg=Can't access video file ^(%videoFile%^)
    goto error
    )
    pushd %outputDirectory%
    
    echo Extracting frames...
    %ffmpegBin% -loglevel error -hide_banner -stats -i "%videoFile%" -vf fps=fps=1/%getFrameEvery%:start_time=0:round=zero -vsync 2 -format rgb -pix_fmt rgba -compression_algo deflate %framePrefix%%%0%paddingDigits%d.tif
    if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    set errMsg=ffmpeg returned error
    goto error
    )
    echo Done!
    echo.
    
    echo Setting base timestamp to files.
    set fileNumber=0
    %exiftoolBin% %exifDateParam% -overwrite_original -globaltimeshift "+0:0:0 0:0:!timeShift!" "%outputDirectory%\%framePrefix%*.tif"
    echo Done!
    echo.
    
    echo Setting timestamp offsets.
    for %%f in ("%outputDirectory%\%framePrefix%*.tif") do (
    set /a "timeShift=!fileNumber!*%getFrameEvery%"
    if !fileNumber! neq 0 %exiftoolBin% -P -m -overwrite_original "-datetimeoriginal+=0:0:0 0:0:!timeShift!" "%%~nxf"
    set /a "fileNumber=!fileNumber!+1"
    )
    echo Done!
    echo.
    echo on
    echo Geotagging images.
    %exiftoolBin% -P -geotag "%gpsDataFile%" "-geotime<${DateTimeOriginal}Z" -overwrite_original "%outputDirectory%\%framePrefix%*.tif"
    echo Done!
    echo.
    
    goto theend
    
    :error
    echo %errMsg%. Exiting.
    
    :theend
    pause
    popd
    endlocal
    
---------------------------------------

I often have multiple video files which are all contained in one gpx file.  I'm using the free program GPX editor to find the correct start time for each video.
```